# Installing CDT plugin to eclipse kepler in windows

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-kepler

I tried to install cdt plugin to eclipse kepler through install new software. There are many sites to do so. But that is not accessible. Please help me!

Comment: Look at [Eclipse CDT Downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can always download a complete "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers" release which already has the CDT built in from this [download link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/keplersr2)